# Superpostion problem, why are resistors shortcircuited?

Tags: circuit-analysis, linear, superposition

We are asked to compute the voltage between points \$A\$ and \$B\$ in the following circuit directly i.e. without using Thevenin's or Norton's Theorem:

[image]

The teacher's solution is divided into three parts, each corresponding to the contribution of a voltage/current source (I'm guessing he is implicitly using the Superposition Theorem):

> **\$25V\$ source contribution:** the total resistance is \$R_T=7k\Omega+(0.5||5)k\Omega = 7.45k\Omega\$. The total current is thus \$I_T=25/7.45 mA = 3.36mA\$. Using a voltage divider we find \$I_{0.5} = 5/5.5 I_T = 3.05mA\$ and \$V_{AB} = -I_{0.5}\cdot 0.5k\Omega = -1.52V\$.

> **\$28V\$ source contribution:** \$0V\$, as the \$0.5k\Omega\$ resistor is shortcircuited.

> **\$10mA\$ source contribution:** \$0V\$, for the same reason.

> The voltage \$V_{AB}\$ is thus \$-1.52V\$

---

***Why are *any* resistors shortcircuited? How are the resistors to be shortcircuited chosen?*** My understanding is that when using the superposition theorem only voltage sources are placed at \$0V\$ (shortcuited) and current sources opencircuited.

Comment: 0V is a short circuit. Wikipedia tells me voltage sources should be short circuits and current sources should be open circuits when using the superposition theorem.

Comment: By looking at the contribution of the current source, do you see that  the right half of the circuit can be ignored? All you have left is a simple voltage divider circuit on the left.

Answer (score 2):

The 500Ω resistor is not short-circuited, but there's effectively only one connection from the left half of the circuit to the right, so the current source and the 28V voltage source can have no effect on the voltage from A to B.

[image]

For superposition you short all independent voltage sources and open all independent current sources, other than the single source (of either kind) that you are computing the contribution from. No other components should be opened or shorted.

Answer (score 2):

The right half of the circuit only connects to node B, there is no path for any current from the 28 V or 10 mA sources to flow to node A, so that whole part of the circuit is irrelevant to the voltage from A to B.

What you end up with is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBJ1NZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which should be simple to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are any resistors shortcircuited? How are the resistors to be
> shortcircuited chosen? My understanding is that when using the
> superposition theorem only voltage sources are placed at 0V and
> current sources shortcircuited.

Resistors are not short-circuited when using superposition to find circuit voltages, voltage sources are shorted. Current sources are opened. The whole point of superposition is to consider one source at a time and turn all other sources off. If the circuit is linear then the voltages you find will be additive once you turn on all sources.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit consists of right part and left part. Since no current of the right part flows through any resistor on the left part, and no voltage of right part can have any effect on the left part, the 10mA source and 28V source are irrelevant, when calculating potential difference between points A and B.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of superposition of effects states that: to determine voltages and currents in each branch of a given linear and time-invariant (LTI) electrical network in which there are N independent generators, one proceeds as follows: currents and voltages are calculated in the network produced by one generator at a time, while the effect of the remaining independent generators has been eliminated. We proceed in this way until the last generator. Then the currents found branch by branch are added algebraically. The same goes for tensions. Eliminating the effect of a voltage generator means that there must be zero voltage between the terminals, so the voltage generator must be replaced with a short circuit. Eliminating the effect of the current generator means zero current so the generator must be replaced with an open circuit.

[image]

Comment: Step1: VAB=0V, Step 2: VAB=1.524V, Step 3: VAB=0V